# Slow down with combining @Scheduled and @Configurable

Tags: java, spring, annotations, scheduled-tasks

we just move our definition of cron jobs from xml based definitions to annotation driven with

```
<task:annotation-driven />
```

we did not configured it further as the defaults are just fine.
We have a few @Scheduled annotations. Everything worked fine. When we deployed it we saw a massive drop in response time from around 20-30 ms average response time to 40-60 average response time.

After just commenting out the one-liner above our response time average dropped again to usual values.

We checked to see what is happening. We are using @Configurable, too. we found that

```
AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(...)
```

is called each time an @Configurable bean is instantiated and it took 15% of execution time.

Additionally ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor is called each time but it took nearly 0% of our execution time, because this method is only doing

```
AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation(method, Scheduled.class);
```

The additional runtime overhead together with @Configurable makes it unsusable for us.

1. Why is AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor doing so much more than ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor?
2. As we don't us @Async at the moment, is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested it with

```
<task:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler" />
<task:executor id="myExecutor"  pool-size="1" />
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" />
```

now it runs faster because of Aspectj mode. Eclipse shows me an error for mode attribute. I don't know why. But it works. It seems that AOPUtils.canApply() is too slow which is used with mode="proxy".

Update:
Still have 80% of my configurable runtime in finding @Scheduled annotations, see picture:
[image]

So if you use @configurable, be aware that there is extra overhead. for every new instance it is checked if this class has methods annotated with @Scheduled. As it is rather strange to have @Configurable and @scheduled on the same class I think searching for @Scheduled annotations should only be done on application context startup.

Comment: the mode error i see is from an old spring plugin in my eclipse IDE

Comment: Hi, long time ago but I'll still try. I'm noticing too a lot of runtime dedicated to find @scheduled annotations. The thing is I don't have any but need task annotation-driven for the async. Is there a workaround to avoid the ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor?